# how do I setup Ant buildscript project.properties file?

Tags: ant, html5boilerplate

Hello I a having problem setting up Ant BuildScript
When I Run ant, the Java Scripts and CSS are not compressed and the and the stylesheet link is not update to a random number.

In the project.properties file I am using the following.

```
file.root.stylesheet    = screen.css
dir.js              = includes/js
dir.js.main         = ${dir.js}
#build.css.scss         = true
dir.css             = css
```

Build sass is turned off because it is already been compiled by compass
I have tried to have a single js file by putting this line around the js scripts

```
<!-- //-beg- concat_js -->
<script src="includes/js/script1.js"></script>
<script src="includes/js/script2.js"></script>
<!-- //-end- concat_js -->
```

The folder structure I am using is the folwing:

- css/
- img/
- includes/sass

  - foundation.scc, screen.scss
- includes/js
- includes/file.php

I am getting the following error's

```
-js.all.minify:
     [echo] Minifying scripts
     [copy] Copying 4 files to c:\projectfolder\intermediate\includes\js
    [apply] c:\projectfolder\includes\js\plugins.js:86: ERROR - Parse error. IE8 (and below) will parse trailing commas in array and object literals incorrectly. If you are targeting newer
versions of JS, set the appropriate language_in option.
    [apply]                     firstName :  "required",
    [apply]                     ^
    [apply]
    [apply] 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
    [apply] Result: 1

-js.main.concat:
     [echo] Concatenating Main JS scripts based on index.html...
     [exec] Result: 1
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\Exception does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\in does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\thread does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\"main" does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\java.io.FileNotFoundException: does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\index.html does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\(Het does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\systeem does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\kan does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\het does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\opgegeven does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\bestand does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\niet does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\vinden) does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\at does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\Method) does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\at does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\at does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97) does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\at does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58) does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\at does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\FindAttribute.main(Unknown does not exist.
   [concat] c:\projectfolder\intermediate\Source) does not exist.
```

I have placed a full error log one my jsfiddle account 
http://jsfiddle.net/piggybattery/bpxBM/1/

Does anyone know how to chain to this structure?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the log? Initial thoughts are: Css isn't the same as css (which is what your dir.css is set to) and you need to set file.root.script to a file that exists.

Comment: also do you really want modernizr concatenated?

Comment: I have update the question. There was a grammar error in Css. And Modernizr does not need to be merged with the other js files.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the trailing comma causing the minification error. that's just a good idea.

Other than that, it looks like there are about a million things that could be going wrong. the build script was created to be pretty easy to use with HTML-Boilerplate structure. When you start to add things like PHP, and SASS and Foundation, there are more and more things that go wrong. It can work with those things, you just need to be aware of the changes your making and reflect them in the build script.

The biggest thing to remember is that the paths in the properties file need to point to real files that Ant and Java can find.

So, from the root of your project (one up from your build directory) make sure the strings that you're building with the `dir.*` and `file.*` properties point to things that exist on disk and in your source code. So, for example, if the script can't find your `file.root.page` (it looks for `index.html` by default. I'm guessing you don't have an index.html in your project?) it can't concatenate the scripts inside the comments. Additionally, if it can't find your `file.root.stylesheet` things will go wrong (is your main CSS file in `css/screen.css`? Is it referenced in your HTML? That's where I swap out the source.) Same for `file.root.script` other things will go wrong (is `file.root.script` set to `script1.js` or `script2.js`? Again, that helps me change the source) Basically every time you make a change from the default HTML5 Boilderplate structure you need to reflect that in those properties.